# Trying to take averages from a list within a dictionary and store them in a new dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the initial dictionary

```
dict = {"Alice":[80,90,70,100,60],"Bob":[70,75,88,77,82],"Cindy":[60,70,90,80,80],"Don":[66,76,76,69,81],"Ellen":[85,88,78,82,68]}
```

I then go through the keys and find the average

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    val = sum(dict[key]) / 5
```

This is where I get stuck.  I know it will cycle through and get me the averages but I'm lost when it comes to saving the value then storing it in a new Dictionary

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you know how to use dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to go directly from one dict to another:

```
d = {"Alice":[80,90,70,100,60],"Bob":[70,75,88,77,82],"Cindy":[60,70,90,80,80],"Don":[66,76,76,69,81],"Ellen":[85,88,78,82,68]}

av = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k, v, in d.items()}
# av is {'Alice': 80.0, 'Bob': 78.4, 'Cindy': 76.0, 'Don': 73.6, 'Ellen': 80.2}
```